# Counting events and testing rxJava

Tags: java, unit-testing, rx-java, assertj

I have following code:

```
private AtomicInteger numberOfGeneratedEvents;

@Before
public void setNumberOfGeneratedEvents() {
    numberOfGeneratedEvents = new AtomicInteger(0);
}

@Test
public void eventsShouldAppearDespiteException() {

    ThreadFactory timerThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("timer-service-%d")
            .build();

    Observable<Long> timerService = Observable
            .interval(1, 1, SECONDS)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, timerThreadFactory)))
            .doOnNext(aLong -> doSomeWork())
            .doOnError(throwable -> doWorkAfterException())
            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retry();

    timerService.subscribe();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assertThat(numberOfGeneratedEvents.get()).isEqualTo(4);
}

private void doWorkAfterException() {
    System.out.println("Exception happened. This code should do something onError. ");
}

private Boolean doSomeWork() {
    numberOfGeneratedEvents.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("Work work. ");
    System.out.println("numberOfGeneratedEvents = " + numberOfGeneratedEvents.get());
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Random null pointer inside the work.");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which translates to following log output:

```
Work work. 
numberOfGeneratedEvents = 1
Work work. 
numberOfGeneratedEvents = 2
Work work. 
numberOfGeneratedEvents = 3
Exception happened. This code should do something onError. 
Work work. 
numberOfGeneratedEvents = 4
Work work. 
numberOfGeneratedEvents = 5
Exception happened. This code should do something onError. 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What concerns me the most and what I do not totally understand is the fact, that last assertion in the last line of the test:

```
   assertThat(numberOfGeneratedEvents.get()).isEqualTo(4);
```

actually goes green and test passes. The other time when I run it I get 4 as last value of `numberOfGeneratedEvents` on the console and test goes green too, so that's fine. What is wrong here and where's the randomness? Am I doing something bad with `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: When the numberOfGeneratedEvents goes up to 5. Does the test pass each time or only sometimes?

Comment: @Mehdi Good call! I've wrapped the testing method in a `for` that run the test 30 times and it failed eventually. Got any more ideas?

Comment: You increment in a thread, then you test on an other thread. try to remove the observeOn so It runs on the current thread

Comment: I doubt this would work, because from what I've gathered `.interval()` creates its own thread called `RxComputationScheduler`. But I will try it later in the evening.

Comment: Okay, some clarification to my comment before - The test failed in the `for` loop because I did not clear the `numberOfGeneratedEvents` variable. It was being increased to some ridiculous numbers before. BUT I've run that test manually few times and it actually went red on 4th or 5th attempt.

Comment: Also I have removed the `observeOn` line and issue is still there. Thanks to @Mehdi and what I've noticed myself is that it looks like there is a sort of 'race condition like' behaviour in this test.  Seems that the `assertThat` line is being executed a split second before last `doSomeWork` method call, hence the test is green.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround which doesn't really explain anything (but works and looks logical) I've toned down the `sleep()` in test down to 4500ms. This way there are only 4 events emited each time.
Doesn't solve what was happening though, so if anyone could enlight me Ill wait in this thread.